# Scheduling running a method at a certain time.

Tags: c#, multithreading, datetime, timer

This is a rather simple issue, but every time I try to find the answer it keeps showing things about Windows Scheduled Tasks, and this is not what this is.

Say my program is basically this:

```
void StartDoingThings()
{
   //At Specific System.DateTime
   DoSomething()

   //At another specific System.Datetime
   DoSomethingElse()
}
```

What do I put instead of those comments to cause those methods to run at separate datetimes.

I could use Thread.Sleep() or even System.Threading.Timers and calculate intervals based off of (DateTimeOfEvent - DateTime.Now), but is there simply something to say (assuming the program is still running):  At 9:30:00 AM on 11/30/2012, perform the method DoAnotherThing() ?

Comment: There is a framework named quartznet, take a look at it. http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: the reason you keep seeing Scheduled Tasks is because that is exactly what it's designed for. to run tasks on a schedule. each task can be it's own operation schedule each one accordingly and let the scheduler manage when to execute.

Comment: It is my understanding (which may be incorrect), that windows Task Scheduling is, "At X time, run this program" and then probably do soemthing with that program.  I am not running another program, I just want something inside my current program to wait until a certain time.  If I am incorrect, definitely help me understand, but given my understanding, the Windows Task Scheduler would not help me run a specific part of my already running program at a certain time.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to break those pieces out into their own components that can be run in Scheduled Tasks?

Comment: The program this will be going in will basically be controlling a device, and taking various readings.  Those controls and the readings will be done at different intervals, starting after a certain time.  It just seemed appropriate that the program be one cohesive unit to do this.  The reading of different sensors will be in their own classes, but I thought that it would be cleaner to have one program handle all of its functions, instead of having separate components like "command_relay.exe" and "read_analog1.exe", etc.

Comment: @Jani I have been looking at it sense you said this, but I am perplexed as to how to run a method of the parent class at a certain time.  The jobs do not have access to the parent class since they in turn have to be classes, for some reason.  They also introduce a race condition since they are threaded.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "schedule" a method to do something at a predetermined time, there are a number of ways to do that.  I would not use `Thread.Sleep()` because that would tie up a thread doing nothing, which is a waste of resources.

A common practice is to use a polling method that wakes up on a regularly timed schedule (let's say once a minute) and review a shared list of tasks to perform.  `System.Timer` can be used for the polling method:

```
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
```

The OnTimedEvent method can contain code that maintains a collection of "tasks" to perform.  When a task's time comes up, the next run of the Timer will cause it to execute.

Comment: So there is nothing built in that would do that just given a dateTime object?  It just seems like such a common thing as doing something at a certain DateTime would be built in.  Some tasks in my program can have delays between them down to a few seconds, and up to a few hours, and obviously telling it to check every second would consume probably more resources than necessary.

Comment: I assume the reason it's not built in is that the system time may be changed, leading to misassumptions (schedules that never "go off")

Comment: That does make sense, but I guess I would just assume that such is the risk of changing your system time while doing a timed task.  If it was just a synchronization change in time, then I would think that they would have a if(time > set_time) to run it, instead of waiting for the exact time (which might be skipped during a time sync).